# I have a problem installing ConvergenceConcepts package in R, it throws an error message saying that 'ConvergenceConcepts' had non-zero exit status

Tags: r

So, I tried to install a package ConvergenceConcepts in RStudio and it threw me an error message:

```
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ConvergenceConcepts’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/ConvergenceConcepts’
```

and a warning, that the package had non-zero exit status. How could I resolve this?

Error loading ConvergenceConcepts library:

```
    Loading required package: tcltk
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘tcltk’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("/usr/bin/otool", c("-L", shQuote(DSO)), stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status 1
```

Error when I try to add tcltk library:

> library(tcltk)

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tcltk’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("/usr/bin/otool", c("-L", shQuote(DSO)), stdout = TRUE) :
  running command ''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so'' had status 1
```

Comment: @MrFlick Now, I added the whole of the error message.

Comment: What if you try `install.packages("ConvergenceConcepts", type="binary")`?

Comment: @MrFlick Now I was able to install the package, but when I tried to load the library it gave me an error, that I need a package tcltk (which is base package). When I try to add library tcltk it again gives me an error: "active developer path does not exist", I will add both of these errors in the original post.

Comment: Have you installed [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/)?

Comment: @MrFlick It gives me a message that this package is not available for R 3.6.3. Now even the "ConvergenceConcepts" package doesn't install even with the binary = TRUE argument added.

Comment: you're using a mac.. just to check (might be dumb), did you install xcode?